Creating a generic Collection view control including placeholder for dynamically injecting contents in .net MAUI
I am trying to create a Generic Collection view control in MAUI which will have all common event handling/Swipe view and other related functionality in that and the page where it is being used, would be able to provide the XAML code/template  for displaying the data.
Something like this:
MyCollectionView.xaml:
<ContentView x:Class="Pages.MyCollectionView" xmlns=...>
    <ContentView.ControlTemplate>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <CollectionView x:Name="myCollectionView" ItemsSource={Binding}>
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                <SwipeView>
                    <SwipeView.LeftItems>
                      <SwipeItems>
                         <SwipeItem BackgroundColor="GreenYellow" Clicked=""/>
                      </SwipeItems>
                </SwipeView.LeftItems>
                   ***<ContentPresenter/>***
                </SwipeView>
                </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>

        </ControlTemplate>
    </ContentView.ControlTemplate>
</ContentView>

MyCollectionView.cs Setting items source for collection view here. Itemssource proerty can come from parent page as well. But to test it is there in the same page.
public partial class MyCollectionView : ContentView
{    
    public List<string>  source = new List<string>()
    protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        var myCollectionView= (CollectionView)GetTemplateChild("myCollectionView");
        if(myCollectionView!=null)
        {
            myCollectionView.ItemsSource = source;
        }
    }
}

MainPage.xaml (Using the above control): Here, I am using MyCollectionView control and providing template in form of grid, which I am hoping ,should be rendered in  section in the MyCollectionView control.
 <StackLayout>
    <ScrollView>
        <ctrl:MyCollectionView>
            <Grid>
               <label Text="{Binding Value}"
            </Grid>
        </ctrl:KCollectionView>
    </ScrollView>
</StackLayout>

I have tried content presenter but no luck. Whenever setting ItemsSource of CollectionView in OnApplyTemplate, throws an exception saying "Parent already added" in android and "No installed component found" in windows.
Not sure this is the right way or can someone redirect me in a proper way of doing this or any example.
I have even tried from code behind itself like this:
public class KCollectionView : CollectionView
{
    public View Contents
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public KCollectionView()
    {
        this.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;
        this.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;
        ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(() =>
        {

            SwipeView swipeView = new SwipeView();
            SwipeItem favoriteSwipeItem = new SwipeItem
            {
                Text = "Favorite",
                IconImageSource = "favorite.png",
                BackgroundColor = Colors.LightGreen
            };
            favoriteSwipeItem.SetBinding(MenuItem.CommandProperty, new Binding("BindingContext.FavoriteCommand", source: this));
            favoriteSwipeItem.SetBinding(MenuItem.CommandParameterProperty, ".");

            SwipeItem deleteSwipeItem = new SwipeItem
            {
                Text = "Delete",
                IconImageSource = "delete.png",
                BackgroundColor = Colors.LightPink
            };
            deleteSwipeItem.SetBinding(MenuItem.CommandProperty, new Binding("BindingContext.DeleteCommand", source: this));
            deleteSwipeItem.SetBinding(MenuItem.CommandParameterProperty, ".");

            swipeView.LeftItems = new SwipeItems { favoriteSwipeItem, deleteSwipeItem };
            
            swipeView.Content = Contents;
            return swipeView;
        });
    }
}

But setting Contents property as a grid in any page's XAMl not working peropely.
<KCollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding}">
           <KCollectionView.Contents>
        <Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" BackgroundColor="gray">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Weight}"/>
        </Grid>
    </KCollectionView.Contents>
</KCollectionView>

Its only displaying last item.

What's the code of KCollectionView.xaml.cs and the whole code of KCollectionView .xaml ?  Could you please post more code snippets about your problem so that we can test on our side?

The second last code snippets represent a collection view(which is create by extending CollectionView class in c# only)
public class KCollectionView : CollectionView
And the last one is using that in a xaml file. Which is also setting KCollectionVew.ItemsSource = List while loading the page.

And what's the full code of MyCollectionView.xaml and MyCollectionView.xaml.cs? If it is convenient for you, could you please share  a Minimal, Reproducible Example here?

@jessis Zhang I have updated the question. The first three snippets shows MyCollectionView control and its usage.

Sorry, I don't really understand the specific use of your code. Can you elaborate on the code and the specific features you want to achieve? And how can we reproduce the problems you mentioned in your thread?
